# Ensemble resnet50 and densenet121 in keras

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras

I want to do a ensemble of resnet50 and desnsenet121, but got an error:

Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_8:0", shape=(?, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "input_8". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

Below is my code for ensembling:

```python
from keras import applications
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPool2D
from keras.models import Model, Input
#from keras.engine.topology import Input
from keras.layers import Average

def resnet50():
    base_model = applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    last = base_model.output
    x = Flatten()(last)
    x = Dense(2000, activation='relu')(x)
    preds = Dense(200, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(base_model.input, preds)
    return model

def densenet121():
    base_model = applications.densenet.DenseNet121(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224,224, 3))
    last = base_model.output
    x = Flatten()(last)
    x = Dense(2000, activation='relu')(x)
    preds = Dense(200, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(base_model.input, preds)
    return model

resnet50_model = resnet50()
densenet121_model = densenet121()
ensembled_models = [resnet50_model,densenet121_model]
def ensemble(models,model_input):
    outputs = [model.outputs[0] for model in models]
    y = Average()(outputs)
    model = Model(model_input,y,name='ensemble')
    return model

model_input = Input(shape=(224,224,3))
ensemble_model = ensemble(ensembled_models,model_input)
```

I thought the reason is when I combine reset50 and densenet121, they have their own input layer, even though I make the input shape to be the same. Different input layer leads to conflict. That's just my guess and I am not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `input_tensor=model_input` when creating the base models.

```py
def resnet50(model_input):
    base_model = applications.resnet50.ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=model_input)
    # ...

def densenet121(model_input):
    base_model = applications.densenet.DenseNet121(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=model_input)
    # ...

model_input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
resnet50_model = resnet50(model_input)
densenet121_model = densenet121(model_input)
```

The base models will then use the provided `model_input` tensor instead of creating separate input tensors of their own.